# The rank of a linear combination of operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Suppose we have two linear operators $X,\,Y$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Now let $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ and consider $Z_{a,b}:=aX+bY$. When we look at their images we clearly have $$im\,Z_{a,b}\subseteq \,im\,X+im\,Y,$$ but in general this inclusion is strict.

1. Is it true that the equality holds whenever we take $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ sufficiently general?
2. What if we know that $X,Y$ satisfy $XY=YX$, that is, if $X,Y$ commute?

Here *sufficiently general* means that $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{C}$ belongs to the complement of a certain finite set (depending on $X,Y$).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 1 is no. For instance, consider
$$
X = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad Y = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}.
$$
I suspect that the answer to 2 is yes. It is clear that the answer must be yes when both $X,Y$ are diagonalizable, because in this case $X$ and $Y$ commute and are therefore simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: Part 1 is now clear to me. Could you please elaborate more part 2? How the particular format of matrices imply the result?

Comment: @amateur On second thought, simultaneous upper-triangularizabiltiy is not enough.

Comment: I will be happy to know of a third thought.

Comment: A negative answer to the second question is given by
 $$ X=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right],\ \ 
    Y=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]. $$